# Application of derivatives.

Tags: calculus

In a distance of 2 meters from a lantern, we let a ball fall. After a second, which is the velocity of the shadow of the ball?. If $y$ is the position of the ball in function of time.

$y(t)=12-4.9t^2$

By similarity of triangles,

$\frac{y}{x}=\frac{12}{x+2}$

Therefore,  $x=\frac{2y(t)}{12-y(t)}\implies \frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{24\frac{dy}{dt}}{(12-y)^2}$.

I don't understand this implication, can anyone explain it step by step, I would appreciate it a lot.

$x(t)'=(2y(t))'(12-y(t))^{-1}+(2y(t))((12-y(t))^{-1})'=\frac{24-9.8t^2}{12-y(t)}+\frac{-(24-9.8t^2)}{-4.9t^4}$....

I am probably doing too many things wrong, excuse me please..

Comment: Is a "lintern" meant to be a "lantern"?  Also:  the expression after the arrow is incomplete.  I mean, is that fraction meant to equal something?

Comment: @lulu Yes, sorry. Edited.

Comment: No problem.  but you still haven't fixed the implication.  Also...I can deduce from the similarity relation that you want the lantern to be a horizontal $2$ away, but you should write that out.

Comment: Ok.  So you have $x(t)$ written as a function of the function $y(t)$.  Now, you could just use the closed form you were given for $y(t)$.  That's not too hard.  What they do here is to use the quotient rule (and the chain rule).  Do you know how to use those?

Comment: Yes, but when I use them, I never get to $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{24\frac{dy}{dt}}{(12-y)^2}$.

Comment: Ok, edit your post to show your calculation.  As a suggestion:  Personally, I always find it easier to use the product rule instead of the quotient.  Thus, I'd write $x(t)=2y(t)\left(12-y(t)\right)^{-1}$ before differentiating.

Comment: I'll post a calculation below.  Note that the implication in the question does   not depend on the simple expression for $y(t)$.  It would be true whatever $y(t)$ was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's rewrite the quotient as a product, so:  $$x(t)=2y\left( 12-y\right)^{-1}$$

Of course $y=y(t)$.

Differentiate via the product rule to get $$x'(t)=\frac {2y'}{12-y}-\frac {2y}{(12-y)^2}\times \frac d{dt}(12-y)=\frac {2y'}{12-y}+\frac {2yy'}{(12-y)^2}$$

All that remains to put the two terms over a common denominator, namely $(12-y)^2$: $$x'(t)=\frac {2y'(12-y)+2yy'}{(12-y)^2}=\frac {24y'}{(12-y)^2}$$  as desired.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

if $$f (x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d} $$
then

$$f'(x)=\frac {df}{dx}=\frac {ad-bc}{(cx+d)^2} $$

and if
$$f (t)=\frac {ag (t)+b}{cg (t)+d} $$
then
$$f'(t)=\frac {df}{dt}=\frac {ad-bc}{(cg (t)+d)^2}\frac {dg}{dt} $$
by chain rule.